# Compliance Server Request

Tags: java-sdk

Still new on stellar but am having a challenge when using the default compliance server for Auth_request. Keep on getting the below error.

```
{
  "code": "invalid_parameter",
  "message": "Invalid parameter.",
  "more_info": "Invalid Data: Tx: AAAAAP1NJXP6tmKl0yflTmNVZSX3ACh/g8d9leEmfOYlwLv3AAAAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAO n38VXrfFKQFyNTyAd3cQtHY7ZDcfFqBny01VralArQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAANNEsf6OUZo0ZPY0pMx3qWNx3FuPkrYr/FWcCdMOidlAAAAAAAAAAAAJiWgAAAAAAAAAABJcC79wAAAEB6Ic6 1jp4sHT0FrWe3NY0vVs0U9WeTzWxr5BR0r3jhBsawpJfA ecMiaFHdiSzehDIWJg/zpVdZ2IPXyuS2MM does not validate as base64;"
}
```

My question is; even after converting the transaction to `toEnvelopeXdrBase64()` why do I keep getting the above error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *urlencode* your request. Without it i.e. all `+` characters are replaced by . You can see that there are spaces in your `tx` param:

```
3jhBsawpJfA ecMiaFHdiSzehDIWJg
           ^
```